# Sort array of structs by a type and then alphabetically by another property

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

Imagine I have the below setup.

I am trying to sort `[first, second, third]` alphabetically and also by `category`.

I'd like `featured` items first and then everything else sorted by `title`.

I tried `let output = [first, second, third].sort { $0.category == $1.category ? $0.category && $1.category == .featured : $0.title < $1.title  }`

But it was a complete disaster.

The end result should be that the sorted titles read `foo` `bar` `baz`

```swift
    enum Category {
        case featured, standard
    }

    struct Article {
        var title: String
        var category: Category
    }

    let first = Article(title: "bar", category: .standard)
    let second = Article(title: "foo", category: .featured)
    let third = Article(title: "boo", category: .standard)

    let output = [first, second, third]
```

Comment: separate them featured and the rest, than sort this two arrays

Comment: They will represent a feed, should I just merge after sorting? Will they lose their order?

Comment: array will not lose order, just concat them with `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## More Scalable Solution

When you have nested sorting, you need to group items first and then sort by those groups. For example we can define priority of the categories with an `Int` value just by constraint the `enum` to `Int`:

```
enum Category: Int {
    case featured // Higher level(value) -> Higher priority in sort
    case standard // Lower level(value) -> Lower priority in sort
}
```

Now you should:

- Group the data before sort:

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: input, by: { $0.category })
```

- Sort groups: (So `Category` cases should have sortable value like an `Int`)

```
let sortedGroups = grouped.sorted { $0.key.rawValue < $1.key.rawValue }
```

- Sort each group's data and map it back to the original array:

```
let result = sortedGroups.map { $0.value.sorted { $0.title < $1.title) } }
```

This approach is **highly scalable** and automated. You just need to define new categories in place of their priority. The rest of the code always works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Articles to be filtered inside the `.featured` category as well (in addition to listing featured before the rest):

```
let res = output.sorted {
    if $0.category == $1.category {
        return $0.title < $1.title
    } else {
        return $0.category == .featured
    }
}
```